# Gmail putting spacing around images in HTML email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I've seen this question answered before on this board, I've tried ALL of the suggestions I still am unable to fix the problem.

I'm trying to send this pages (http://shannon-brown.com/clients/Digital17/UB-Email.html) as an HTML email.  When I open it in a Gmail account, there are a couple pixels of white padding surrounding my images.

I've tried all of these:

```
display: block
padding: 0
margin: 0
font-size: 0
font-size: 1px
line-height: 0
line-height: 1px
```

I've tried all these solutions on the image tags and the TD tags.  Please help, I'm going bonkers.

Comment: Although you have to be careful, have you tried using Firebug or Chrome Console to inspect the email in the browser and find the padding/margin problem element?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the dreaded `!important` statement to resolve the issue. Sadly, sometimes it is necessary when you can't control somebody else's CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if those extra white pixels are `border`-related, maybe something like

`border:2px white solid`

Try `border:0;`

This seems to suggest it might be a `border`

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6f889773f4f0fa76&hl=en